# Need to get only the mode value without index and data type Python

Tags: python, indexing, data-analysis, mode, imputation

I am trying to extract the count of mode for each column in python to find the percentage of the highest frequency to remove the columns with low variance

```
col = test_df.columns   
for i in  col:
    x = test_df[i].mode()
    y = test_df[i][test_df[i]==x][i]
    print(i,x,y) 


ValueError: Can only compare identically-labelled Series objects



x = test_df['1stFlrSF'].mode()
x


0    864
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try below line to get only the mode value without displaying its data type
x[0].

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers))